# DMesh equivalent program for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation

Any program like [DMesh](http://dmesh.thedofl.com/) for Linux?

Answer (score 1):

**ADmesh**

ADmesh is the dmesh which is in [Ubuntu main repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/admesh)

Can install with

```
sudo apt-get install admesh
```

Comment: It does not support bitmap files right?